# Write Pixels to a Texture via OpenGL ES Android

Tags: android, arrays, opengl-es, textures

I'm trying to do some pixel work in a texture old school by accessing it using an array. My approach is to generate a texture, then use that texture each successive frame write and modify my texture as necessary. However, when I run this code in the Android Emulator, all I get is a white image. My texture size is a power of two, so I was a bit surprised. If anything, I would have expected to see a completely black image. Here is my custom renderer code:

```
package com.gltest;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import java.nio.IntBuffer;
import java.nio.ShortBuffer;

import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;
import android.opengl.GLU;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView.Renderer;

public class OpenGLRenderer implements Renderer {

    private ByteBuffer buf;
    private int cwidth, cheight;
    private FloatBuffer vertexBuffer, texelBuffer;
    private ShortBuffer indexBuffer;
    int[] textures = new int[1];

    float vertices[] = {
               0.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
               0.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
               1.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
               1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f
        };
    private float texels[] = {
            0.0f, 1.0f,
            0.0f, 0.0f,
            1.0f, 0.0f,
            1.0f, 1.0f
        };
    private short[] indices = { 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3 };

    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        updateTexture(gl);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
        gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        GLU.gluOrtho2D(gl, 0, width, 0, height);
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();

        buf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(128 * 128 * 3).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        cwidth = width;
        cheight= height;;

        for( int i=0; i<vertices.length; i+=3 ) {
            vertices[i] *= cwidth;
            vertices[i+1] *= cheight;
        }
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        gl.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);
        gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_NEAREST);
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_NEAREST);
        gl.glTexImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, 128, 128, 0, GL10.GL_RGB, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buf);

        ByteBuffer vbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4);
        vbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        vertexBuffer = vbb.asFloatBuffer();
        vertexBuffer.put(vertices);
        vertexBuffer.position(0);

        ByteBuffer tbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(texels.length * 4);
        tbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        texelBuffer = tbb.asFloatBuffer();
        texelBuffer.put(texels);
        texelBuffer.position(0);

        ByteBuffer ibb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(indices.length * 2);
        ibb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        indexBuffer = ibb.asShortBuffer();
        indexBuffer.put(indices);
        indexBuffer.position(0);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
        gl.glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f);  
        gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_SMOOTH);
        gl.glClearDepthf(1.0f);
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        gl.glDepthFunc(GL10.GL_LEQUAL);
        gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_NICEST);
    }

    void updateTexture(GL10 gl)
    {   
        // Update pixels
        // write random r g or b values to random locations
        for(int y = 0; y < 128; ++y)        
            for(int x = 0; x < 128; ++x)
                buf.put(x+y*128, (byte)(Math.random()*255));

        buf.position(0);
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        gl.glBindTexture(gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);

        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);

        gl.glTexSubImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, 128, 128, GL10.GL_RGB, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buf);
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
        gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, texelBuffer);
        gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);

        gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, indices.length, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, indexBuffer);

        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly I do not believe it is a very convenient solution performance wise.

This kind of alteration/effects should be done in a programmable pipeline model such as OPENGL ES 2.0 using vertex and fragment shaders.

The solution you are trying to achieve is not convenient for the following reasons:

- The load is entirely on the CPU and you are not using the power of the GPU at all
- Texture data manipulation functions are well known to be a performance killer for nowadays GPUs

I strongly suggest you to implement the effects possibly in a fragment shader to have the best performances possible.

Comment: This looks to be the right idea. But if I'm calling gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_texture, v_texcoord); I still need to update every texel. How do I get my byte/int array into that

Comment: Honestly it depends a lot on what you need to do. Often it is not convenient to have the effects calculation in real time and you have to cheat with pre-calculated effects. But it all depends on your actual need, I don't have enough information on it.

Consider that if you implment the effect on the CPU you will have soon the CPU flooded by things to do for example in a game, handling input, graphics, effects, opengl calls, logic, AI, physics...

Try to delegate as much you can on the GPU. This is a gold rule to be followed :)

Answer (score 0):

After some poking around, I've discovered that gl.glTexSubImage2D is not supported in GLES 1.1 on Android (it's built in but it doesn't do anything: https://www.google.com/search?ix=hea&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=android+opengl+glTexSubImage2D)

Also, so no one else wastes their time in the future, forget about trying to use glDrawPixels to send to the framebuffer. That isn't support either, in *any* GLES 1.1 / 2.0 implementation (Android, iPhone) etc.

The solution is to use the NDK as outlined in this excellent article by some coder named "Richard Quirk" who has his own blog: http://quirkygba.blogspot.com/2010/10/android-native-coding-in-c.html and, as it happens, also is a Stack Overflow regular: https://stackoverflow.com/users/4596/richq

Thanks Richard!